# How can I create a page with my Archive template in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

When I go to edit my site, I see some templates:

[image]

I've edited the Archive template and now I want to create a page with that template.

I'm going to `Pages -> Add new` then the editor will open and I can see "Template: Page":

[image]

Trying to change from "Page" to "Archive" but I don't see the option:

[image]

How can I create a page based on the Archive template?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by creating a new page, adding a title, then click to add element and search for "Blog":

[image]

This is the result:

[image]